# Cant install ubuntu and cant find windows 7 partition

Tags: boot, partitioning

I tried to install Ubuntu, but when I chose the partition on which I wanted to install it, my computer suddenly froze and refused to continue the installation process. So I was obliged to restart it.

But after I restarted I couldn't access Windows 7 that I already had in it. I used the windows 7 CD to access the command prompt then I found that my local drive C: had shrunk in size and got the new name Linux instead of the local drive. I could not install Windows on my heard disk.

I tried Ubuntu without installing it using CD and was surprised to find that the partition  containing old Windows 7 is still there and showing its normal size 265 GB. How can I recover my windows 7 installation / partition?

Comment: What's "got blocked" mean? And were you trying to overwrite your old windows partition? And what do you want to do, recover the windows partition, delete it & install Ubuntu?

Comment: I want to recover the windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

Yours sounds like a complicated situation, I'm not sure what shape your hard drive & Windows partition is in, being able to see it in a live Ubuntu, but the Windows disk not seeing it...

I would try (running a live Ubuntu cd - "try without installing") to mount the windows partition (mounted read-only = `ro` just in case) and take a look at the files, see if they're all there & aren't corrupted:

To find out what device the partition's on, you can check gparted, or gnome disk utility (Disks), or run `lsblk` or `sudo blkid`. It's probably similar to `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sdb1`.

In a terminal, after creating an empty folder for a mount point (ex. `sudo mkdir -p /media/win`), mount it read only with `sudo mount -r /dev/[the right one] /media/win`
[Searched for an easy answer for "how to mount windows read only" but didn't find one oddly]

If the windows partition looks good, you could try to repair it's bootloader. Read ["How can I repair the Windows 8 EFI Bootloader?" on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader)  for help - it says Windows 8, but questions about Windows 7 get marked as a duplicate of that one... I'm not too sure about the EFI being different.

---

Or if the wndows partition doesn't look good, you could try `testdisk` that might be able to recover the partition &/or boot loader too. [READ THE GUIDES & DOCUMENTATION](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), it could do a lot of damage if you're not careful. [This "basic" step-by-step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) might be helpful.